# Javascript in aspx to get variable path

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using jquery.mb.mini audio player and i got below code in my aspx page which works fine.

```
<a id="m5" class="audio {skin:'green', autoPlay:false, addShadow:false,addGradientOverlay:true}" href="Folder 1/Audio1.mp3">Audio1 mp3</a>
```

My question is that how can i change href path in above code to be a variable path according to two dropdowns selected values.  Because i also got two dropdowns on aspx page and one of them got value "Folder 1" and other one got value "Audio1".  I tried doing it by below code but its not working.

### Javascript in aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("DropDownList1").value + "/" + document.getElementById("DropDownList2").value + '.mp3';
        return x;
    }
</script>


<a id="m5" class="audio {skin:'green', autoPlay:false, addShadow:false,addGradientOverlay:true}" href='javascript:myFunction()'>Audio1 mp3</a>
```

Does anybody can help that how i can achieve this?

Dropdown code in aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="FldrName" 
    DataValueField="FldrName" Height="25px" Width="250px">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/AD.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [FldrName] FROM [Folders]">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<br />
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" DataTextField="Audio" DataValueField="Audio" 
    Height="25px" Width="250px">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" DataFile="~/AD.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Audio] FROM [Aduios] WHERE ([FldrName] = ?)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="FldrName" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Basically audio player is not playing audio. It plays audio if I keep the path like href="Folder 1/Audio1.mp3". I am working on MS Visual Web Developer Express 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to have the url generated when the link is clicked.
This is the wrong approach.  You want the href to be updated when the dropdowns change.

Instead of setting the href of the link to a javascript function. You should add a handler to the the dropdowns, that will call `myFunction()` when they change.  Then in `myFunction()` update the href of the anchor link.   That way, the href will already be set before you click it.  Not after, and the click will call the url, not a function.

So, the function would be

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("DropDownList1").value + "/" + document.getElementById("DropDownList2").value + '.mp3';
    document.getElementById('m5').href = x;
}
```

I'll have to see the markup for the dropdown lists to show you how to add the handler.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onchange="myFunction();"
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataTextField="FldrName" 
    DataValueField="FldrName" Height="25px" Width="250px">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: @KamranRasheed, sorry for the delay, I had to run to a meeting.  I added an `onchange` handler to the dropdown, you can add the exact same thing to the other dropdown and it should work.  For the hyperlink, you should have a default url set in the `href` property in case someone clicks on it before changing a dropdown.

Comment: Thanks Smeegs.  I did as you said but now I am getting error saying "End of statement expected" and highlighting line function myFunction() {